# Smooth move for camera in three.js

Tags: webgl, three.js

I'm trying to modify panorama equirectangula player ( https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_panorama_equirectangular.html ) to add some smooth move to camera. Is there any chance to make it move like in cube example ( https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/canvas_geometry_cube.html ), without breaking move on mousedown but smooth fade out?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript raw mouse input event rate is too low for smooth updating. I assume mouse input events are generated on much lower frequency than your FPS.

The solution would interpolate between the mouse input events. First Person Shooters call this mouse smoothing. Filter incoming events, interpolate using a spline, add momentum (a.k.a. iPhone style scrolling), etc.